# PDFBOX merge several PDF without render Optional Content Group visibility

Tags: pdf, merge, pdfbox

In my project, I need to merge several pdf documents. Each document contains only one page with several optional content groups (OCG). Many OCGs are not activated and are not visible in the pdf viewer application.

After merging this pdf with PDFMergerUtility, I get merged PDF files.
In this pdf, except for the first page which is correct, in all other pages, all the ocg are visible. The previously disabled ocg becomes visible.

I don't know now if I'm using PDFMergerUtility correctly or if it's a bug, do you know, how to merge several pdf in a single file with the correct display ocg in java?

Is it possible to completely delete an OCG in pdf format?

Edit :
 I currently use pdfbox-app-2.0.6, I will try with 2.0.7.

I use this pdf with all OCG disable : [simple pdf layer exemple](http://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_layer_new.pdf)
and I try to merge with a copy of himself.
Sorry my other pdf are confidentiel.

Comment: I will try soon as possible with 2.0.7, actually i use 2.0.6.

Comment: I have opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3973 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3972. On a second thought, I'm not sure whether it is a bug. Should identical names be merged or should both exist?

Comment: To remove the OCG completely, just remove OCProperties from the document catalog: `doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOCProperties(null)`.

Comment: Thank you @Tilman Hausherr, for your help. I have seeing on jira that you have successfuly resolve the problem ? Do you have an idea when 2.0.8 version should be available ? Or maybe i can import the trunk ?
I can actually delete the OCP properties, in this case all ocg reappear, but I want to delete them.
My opinion after a merge, ocg with the same layer name, they must be renamed (version with page number for example) and both must exist.

Comment: I resolved another problem that I also noticed while looking at your file, but not the main one, sadly. 2.0.8 should be out in the next few weeks. I'm still thinking about the main problem... I don't know much about OCGs, I never use them, so this isn't so easy. The best would be to set yourself (you must register) as a watcher on that JIRA issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in issue [PDFBOX-3973](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3973) and will be part of release 2.0.14 in a few weeks / months. It is available as a [snapshot](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.14-SNAPSHOT/) until release.

In the merged file both OCGs will coexist.